# Why does Arrays.deepEquals(Object[]arr1,Object[]arr2) works for primitive multidimensional arrays like int[][] ,float[][] etc?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, primitive, deepequals

From method signature it is very clear that method accepts the argument of type Object[] but still this method works perfectly fine for primitive multidimensional arrays ?(like int[][],float[][] etc)
(However it shows error for primitive one dimensional array (like int[],float[] etc))

Ex:

```
      int[][]arr=new int[2][3];
      arr[0][0]=1;
      arr[0][1]=2;
      arr[0][2]=3;
      arr[1][0]=4;
      arr[1][1]=5;
      arr[1][2]=6;
      int[][]arr1=new int[2][3];
      arr1[0][0]=1;
      arr1[0][1]=2;
      arr1[0][2]=3;
      arr1[1][0]=4;
      arr1[1][1]=5;
      arr1[1][2]=6;

      System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(arr,arr1));

      Output: true


Ex:  
     int[]arr={1,2,3,4,5};
     int[]arr1={1,2,3,4,5};
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepEquals(arr,arr1));//Error
/*"The method deepEquals(Object[], Object[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[], int[])"*/
```

the same issue is with Arrays.deepToString(Object[]) From method signature it is very clear that this method too accepts the argument of type Object[] but still it works perfectly fine for primitive multidimensional arrays ?(like int[][],float[][] etc)(However it shows error for primitive one dimensional array (like int[],float[] etc))

```
  Ex:
      int[][]arr=new int[2][3];
      arr[0][0]=1;
      arr[0][1]=2;
      arr[0][2]=3;
      arr[1][0]=4;
      arr[1][1]=5;
      arr[1][2]=6;

      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));

      Output: [[1, 3, 0], [4, 5, 6]]


 Ex:

     int[]arr={1,2,3,4,5}; 
     System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr)); //Error
    //"The method deepToString(Object[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (int[])"
```

Edit:

I would also like to add few points from my end as well.

1: Subtyping in Java :

```
What is subtyping?
```

=>Subtyping is a key feature of object-oriented
programming languages such as Java. In Java, Sis a subtype of T if S
extends or implements T. Subtyping is transitive, meaning that if R is a
subtype of S, then R is also a subtype of T (T is the super type of both
Sand R).String is a subtype of Object, because the String class is a
subclass of the Object class.

```
int is not a subtype of Object, because none of Java's primitive types 
are subtypes of any reference type.

StringBuilder is not a subtype of String, because the StringBuilder 
class is not a subclass of the String class.

 HashMap<Candidate,Double> is a subtype of Map<Candidate,Double>, 
 because the HashMap class implements the Map interface and the type 
 parameters match.

 HashMap<Candidate,Double> is not a subtype of Map<String,Ballot>, even 
 though the HashMap class implements the Map interface, because the type 
 parameters do not match.
```

2:  Subtyping among Array Types :

```
The following rules define the direct supertype relation among array 
types:

If S and T are both reference types, then S[] >1 T[] iff S >1 T.

Object >1 Object[]

Cloneable >1 Object[]

java.io.Serializable >1 Object[]

If P is a primitive type, then:

Object >1 P[]

Cloneable >1 P[]

java.io.Serializable >1 P[]
```

3: The direct superclass of an array type is Object.

4: Every array type implements the interfaces Cloneable and
java.io.Serializable.

5:In the Java programming language, arrays are objects , are dynamically
created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object. All methods of
class Object may be invoked on an array.

6: An object is a class instance or an array.

7: The reference values (often just references) are pointers to these
objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

8: A class instance is explicitly created by a class instance
creation expression.

9: An array is explicitly created by an array creation expression .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal question asked is:

> Why does `Arrays.deepEquals(Object[] arr1, Object[] arr2)` work for primitive multidimensional arrays like `int[][]`, `float[][]` etc?

The simple answer to that is "because the javadoc says so".  See [@Old Dog Programmer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76125227/139985) for details.

---

But the **real** question being asked (as I understand it) is:

> Why does it work for `int[][]`, `float[][]` etc but not for `int[]`, `float[]` etc?

This is a consequence of the way that subtyping and multidimensional array types work in Java.  In Java there is really no such thing as a multidimensional array type<sup>1</sup>.  For example, the type `int[][]` is actually an "array of arrays of `int`".   The "array of `int`" part is a primitive array type.

According to the Java subtyping rules, all arrays (including 1-D primitive arrays such as `int[]`) are subtypes of `Object`.  That means that `int[][]` ("array of arrays of `int`") is a subtype of `Object[]` ("array of `Object`").

By contrast an `int[]` is NOT a subtype of `Object[]` since `int` is not a subtype of `Object`.

That means that `Arrays.deepEquals` doesn't work for primitive arrays (i.e. the method is not applicable to the arguments) but it does work for *arrays of* primitive arrays; i.e. multidimensional primitive arrays.  The practical solution is to use the `Arrays.equals` overloads when comparing 1-D primitive arrays.

---

<sup>1 - JLS Chapter 1 states: *"The language supports arrays of arrays, rather than multidimensional arrays."*</sup>

Comment: If someone wants the JLS references, I could track them down.  It will be in the section that defines subtyping.

Comment: Thankyou.I was thinking of the same,your answer validated my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It works because `Arrays.deepEquals` was written to work for 2D arrays of primitives. The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) specifies it will work. Here is a quote, in which I emphasized the most relevant line:

> Two possibly null elements e1 and e2 are deeply equal if any of the following conditions hold:

> - e1 and e2 are both arrays of object reference types, and Arrays.deepEquals(e1, e2) would return true
> - **e1 and e2 are arrays of the same primitive type, and the appropriate overloading of Arrays.equals(e1, e2) would return true.**
> - e1 == e2
> - e1.equals(e2) would return true.
>   Note that this definition permits null elements at any depth.

How was it made to work? We can look at the [source code](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Arrays-source.html) for the method. It contains an `if ... else` chain that checks if the parameters are each an`instanceof` the same type of primitive array.

The code for the `deepToString` method contains a similar `if ... else` chain.